# JSLint reports "Insecure ^" for my regex -- what does that mean?

Tags: regex, jslint

I'm trying to get my Javascript code 100% JSLint clean.

I've got a regular expression:

```
 linkRgx = /https?:\/\/[^\s;|\\*'"!,()<>]+/g;
```

JSLint reports:

```
 Insecure '^'
```

What makes the use of the negation of the character set "insecure" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[^\s;|\\*'"!,()<>]` matches any ASCII character other than the ones listed, and any non-ASCII character.  Since JavaScript strings are Unicode-aware, that means every character known to Unicode.  I can see a lot of potential for mischief there.

Rather than disable the warning, I would rewrite the character class to match the characters you *do* want to allow, as this regex from the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689) does:

```
/\bhttps?:\/\/[-\w+&@#/%?=~|$!:,.;]*[\w+&@#/%=~|$]/g
```

Answer (score 5):

(answering my own question) I did some digging... JSLint documentation says:

> Disallow insecure . and [^...]. in /RegExp/   regexp: true if . and [^...] should not be allowed in RegExp literals. These forms should not be used when validating in secure applications.

What I have done is disable the JSLint error for the offending line (as I'm not dealing with needing to be secure from potentially malicious user input:

```
/*jslint regexp: false*/
.... Javascript statement(s) ....
/*jslint regexp: true*/
```

Comment: I actually changed my code to use Alan's suggestion above, as that regex is rigorous.

Comment: Actually, you need to switch the lines.  It's regexp: true then regexp: false

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
/*jslint regexp: true*/
linkRgx = /https?:\/\/[^\s;|\\*'"!,()<>]+/g;
/*jslint regexp: false*/
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? What does that comment line disable/enable and why it is needed in this case?