# Regex character class inside character range failing intellij's jsLint inspection

Tags: javascript, regex, intellij-idea, jslint

[image]

What is the easiest way to rectify my failing inspection?  There is no option in intellij (that I can find) to allow character classes inside a character range.

Comment: why do you have `\w` inside `[]`?

Comment: @Mathletics becuase I know nothing about regex's and just copied from another SO answer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having `\w` in an `[]`.

Comment: @NimChimpsky as per my answer below, because the un-escaped hyphen has special meaning inside a character class (it creates a "range" of included characters, eg `a-z` or `0-9`) I'd expect this regex is not correct as it sits (I'm assuming the intent of the hyphen in your character class is to allow a _literal_ hyphen in the target string at that point in the email address?).  As such, would you mind providing a reference the specific SO answer so that it can be corrected if/as appropriate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to allow a literal hyphen `-` in a character class, you need to put it immediately after the opening `[` (Refer "Character Classes" section at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) or immediately prior to the closing `]` (I've found works in some languages at least), else it's deemed to signify a range.

And note also this comment by @IanMackinnon on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109214/jslint-insecure-in-regular-expression) (although I couldn't find an authoritative source for this after a very brief search): "*explicitly escaping hyphens in character classes is another JSLint recommendation.*" - this was written in the context of *literal* hyphens.  Regardless of if jsLint *needs* this or not to pass inspection, it's probably good practice to do this in order to future-proof the literal hyphen in case a future developer accidentally turns the class into a range by putting something between the (un-escaped) hyphen and the opening (or closing) bracket.

I therefore think the section of your regex that currently reads as `[\w-+\s]` should be re-written as `[\-\w+\s]`).

And the subsequent `[\w-+]` as `[\-\w+]`, etc...

Comment: The first bit is wrong - he is passing a regex literal to the RegExp contructor (unnecessarily), and `\w` would only need to be `\\w` if it was a string. He either needs to escape the hyphen `\-` or put it at the start or end of the class as you suggest.

Comment: @MikeM Indeed - Thanks for highlighting my error, have updated my answer to reflect.