# Why is [^...] in /RegExp/ not secure?

Tags: javascript, regex

[jslint](http://jslint.com/) detects my following code as not secure:

```
/([^\n]+)([\n\s]*)/g
```

Later I learned there is a lint option:

> ". and [^...] in /RegExp/"

which you can find over [here](http://jslint.com/)

Why is it not secure?

Comment: Provide the whole reproducible code chunk so that we could see that as well.

Comment: This would be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4109254/251311

Comment: @Mörre it at least refers to the official documentation and cites it

Comment: @zerkms Why? They all say the same thing. Pick any. You link to an answer - which is not a duplicate, you have to link to a question :) My link cites the jslint doc, as you seem to have overlooked. There is nothing else to gain. It does not matter. Pick any. Why are we having this conversation?

Comment: Am I the only who thinks that JSLint tries to do much more job than it intended to do? (not to mention it does it in a terrible manner)

Comment: js lint is designed to guard again human mistakes and unreadble syntax, not errors or security risks

Comment: @dandavis: seems like it also tries to check the security as well. I will not be surprised if one day it will complain on grammar in code comments

Comment: @zerkms I agree, jshint is much better. Magic warnings like this give developers a false-sense of security. It would only be insecure in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the [^...] character you're allowing almost anything in your regex and jshint detects a security risk.

This is what [jslint docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) says about [^...]:

> true if . and [^...] should be allowed in RegExp literals. They match
>   more material than might be expected, allowing attackers to confuse
>   applications. These forms should not be used when validating in secure
>   applications.