# I am getting a JSLint insecure exception error when trying to validate a password in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

while trying to validate the password with regular expression in the .js file I am getting the error as **Run JSLint (if jslint.scan.dir=/src/...) Failed**

this happens while building the application
got the following exception

```
Insecure '.'.
`var passw= /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;`
                                                  ^
```

```js
passwordPatternCheck : function passwordPatternCheck() {
  var patternCheck = function passPatternCheck(submittedValues, validation) {
    var result = null;
    var submitted = submittedValues[validation.name];
    var passw= /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
    if (submitted && !submitted.match(passw)) {
      var displayName = validation.label || validation.name;
      result = i18n("Should have 8 or more characters with atlease one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and one special character as %s.", displayName);
    }
    return result;
  };
  return patternCheck;
},
```

tried to escape the dot[.] but the regex is not working as expected

```
(?=\.*[A-Z])(?=\.*[a-z])(?=\.*[0-9])(?=\.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$
```

Comment: The regex is safe to use, JSLint is too strict. You could use the inverse classes in the lookaheads though: `/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^@$!%*?&]*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/` to make it even safer. But JSLint would still nag you without any good reason.

Comment: I tried the above regex but again getting the below exception in the new place. Could you please suggest me a alternate solution for this.  
Insecure '^'.
                               var passw= /^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^@$!%*?&]*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
                                                                                         ^

Comment: There is no need for a solution as I said. The regexps are fine, JSLint is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378133/3832970